# Does having an SSL certificate make ssh/sftp connections any more automatic?

Tags: ssh, security, ssl-certificate

When I log in to a new machine (or from a new machine) using ssh/sftp, I get prompted with the "here's this random string of hex digits; should I trust it?" question.  And, since I never have the right stuff in front of me to figure out whether or not the signature is good, I typically think about the network in use and decide accordingly -- perhaps going as far as accepting the signature without actually logging in and then comparing it to what-should-be-the-same signatures found on other machines/logins .ssh directories.

If I get an SSL certificate for my "new" destination machine (say, one of the $4.99 ones from one of the many vendors around the web), can I use that to make the process any more secure/painless (like, would the "do you want to trust that this machine is who it says it is" prompt disappear)?  Or are the two (SSL and ssh/sftp) completely disjoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No, SSH does not use the SSL protocol, nor X.509 certificates.**

Besides, even if it did, you would need to log in over SSH to *install* a SSL certificate to your server, which would defeat the whole point – at least in the "when I log in to a new machine" case.

If you frequently set up new servers, write a script that would query a given server's fingerprint from multiple different locations (for example, using `pssh` and `ssh-keyscan`). If all locations see the same fingerprint, then you're fine.

If you frequently connect from untrusted computers, pick one of your servers to act as a "gateway", write down its fingerprint, and carry it in your wallet/phone/whatever; then make all connections only through that server.

---

Side note: OpenSSH 6.x *does* have its own certificate format, but it does not integrate with the existing X.509 PKI and only supports one level of "authorities", so it's only useful when connecting to already-set-up servers from an already-configured client.

The same downside – the need for explicit configuration – also applies to OpenSSH's support for verifying fingerprints over DNSSEC.

Finally, there do exist a few patches for using X.509 within SSH – one used by US DoD, one used by Globus Toolkit (GSI-SSH), possibly others – but they all have the exact same problems as above: it only becomes more automatic when deployed in large organizations. Trying to set up GSI-SSH at home wouldn't save you any time, only waste more of it.